# How to suppress 'Broken pipe' ClientAbortedException with Grails RxController?

Tags: grails, reactive-programming, tomcat8, rx-java2, server-sent-events

I've implemented an SSE controller using the RxController trait with Grails 3.3.1. The basic Observable chain looks as follows:

```
class SseController implements RxController {

def index() {
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    PublishSubject subject = PublishSubject.create()
    Observable publishedObservable = subject.publish().autoConnect().observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    rx.stream(publishedObservable
    .doOnSubscribe {
        log.info("User ${user.username} subscribed to notifications with thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }.map {
        log.info("User event thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        rx.event([type: 'notification'], "${it}")
    }.mergeWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map {
        if (it % 100 == 0) log.info("Sending heartbeat on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        rx.event("$it")
    }.doFinally {
        println "Terminating subscriber for ${user.username}"
    }))
}
```

This is a very basic chain because I'm just establishing a POC here. Anyway, it's all working fine. The problem I'm having is when the user reloads the browser page, thereby closing the original EventSource connection, it triggers a stacktrace that I can't seem to suppress - which I want to do because it's not relevant to me and will just clog up my logs.

```
2018-06-16 10:56:07.044  INFO --- [ionThreadPool-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : An error occurred in processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1261)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:581)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:272)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1510)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
at org.grails.plugins.rx.web.RxResultSubscriber.onNext(RxResultSubscriber.groovy:178)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit(ObservableFlatMap.java:262)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:559)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:103)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.onNext(ObservableDoFinally.java:82)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:64)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableInterval$IntervalObserver.run(ObservableInterval.java:83)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.run(ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.java:39)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

as well as

```
2018-06-16 10:56:07.164 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.g.plugins.rx.web.RxResultSubscriber: Async Dispatch Error: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1261)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:581)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:272)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1510)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159)
at org.grails.plugins.rx.web.RxResultSubscriber.onNext(RxResultSubscriber.groovy:178)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit(ObservableFlatMap.java:262)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:559)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:103)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.onNext(ObservableDoFinally.java:82)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:64)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableInterval$IntervalObserver.run(ObservableInterval.java:83)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.run(ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.java:39)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried figuring out if I can intercept the exception being thrown up the stack but to no avail.

Does anybody have any ideas how to get rid of these errors being logged?